# Error saying that argument must be a string

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm trying to post in **/register** for a simply user authentication webpage and I am getting an error that states:

*The "password" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView.*

I tried looking in my code to see if I'm missing **.toString** but it looks like I've added it in the post request, not sure why I'm getting the error.

Here's what I have for the **register.ejs** template.

```
<div class="form__group field">
  <input type="password" class="form__field" placeholder="Password" name="password" id='password' required />
  <label for="password" class="form__label">Password</label>
</div>
```

Then my **routes.js** file.

```
const genPassword = require('./../utils/passportUtils').genPassword;

router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
  const saltHash = genPassword(req.body.pw);

  const salt = saltHash.salt;
  const hash = saltHash.hash;

  const newUser = new User({
    username: req.body.uname,
    hash: hash,
    salt: salt,
  });

  newUser.save().then((user) => {
    console.log(user);
  });

  res.redirect('/welcome');
});

router.get('/register', (req, res, next) => res.render('pages/register'));

module.exports = router;
```

Current **passport.js** file.

```
const customFields = {
  usernameField: 'uname',
  passwordField: 'pw',
};

const verifyCallback = (username, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ username: username })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false);
      }

      const isValid = validPassword(password, user.hash, user.salt);

      if (isValid) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err);
    });
};

const strategy = new LocalStrategy(customFields, verifyCallback);
```

Lastly, my **passportUtils.js** file.

```
function genPassword(password) {
  const salt = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
  const genHash = crypto
    .pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512')
    .toString('hex');

  return {
    salt: salt,
    hash: genHash,
  };
}

function validPassword(password, hash, salt) {
  const hashVerify = crypto
    .pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, 10000, 64, 'sha512')
    .toString('hex');

  return hash === hashVerify;
}

module.exports.validPassword = validPassword;
module.exports.genPassword = genPassword;
```

Thanks in advance! I did add the modules I needed for each file, I just didn't add them in the above example code. Let me know if I'm missing any code that you want to see too. Still learning.

Comment: Please make the change value of 'name' attribute of input  type password as 'pw' then it will work. As you are accessing it as pw in the req.body.  or Please make the change in the backend as req.body.password. Either will work.

Comment: Thank you! @AmaranadhMeda that worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make this change to your .ejs file

```
<div class="form__group field">
<input type="password" class="form__field" placeholder="Password" 
name="pw" id='password' required />
<label for="password" class="form__label">Password</label>
</div>
```